# Dll not found vcruntime140.dll when deploying as file for x86 and x64

Tags: c#, dll, native, vcredist

Currently i get the error message, that `vcruntime140.dll` was not found on a client computer. But I'm delivering the following dlls for `x64` and `x86`:

1. vcruntime140.dll
2. vccorlib140.dll
3. msvcp140.dll
4. concrt140.dll

in a `\bin32\` and `\bin64\` directory (for each platform). This directories are registered on application startup:

Dll-Import

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool AddDllDirectory(string lpPathName);
```

And for `x86` the registration code:

```
if (System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major > 5)
{
    AddDllDirectory(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\bin32");
}
else
{
    SetDllDirectory(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\bin32");
}
```

What do I need to do additionally?

Thank you all!

Comment: `AddDllDirectory` and `SetDllDirectory` only affect subsequent calls to `LoadLibrary`. When does your application "start up"? If you have a class that directly or indirectly refers to code through a static constructor, for example, that code may execute before anything you do. (Also, you're not actually checking if the calls succeed. You should.)

Comment: It is the first thing i do in program.cs

Comment: Oh, and more seriously -- `AddDllDirectory` returns a `DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE`, not a `bool` (which you can marshal as an `IntPtr`). These functions are not simply interchangeable. (And, like I said, check their return values and `throw new Win32Exception()` if they return `false`/`IntPtr.Zero`, at present they can fail silently.)

Comment: There are too many .NET programmers that are confounded by the difference between the solution platform and the platform target.  Add `if (IntPtr.Size != 4) throw new Exception("Not actually a 32-bit process");`

Comment: In this case it's only a x86 process, so this should not be the problem.